# phpMyAdmin Import Excel spreadsheet with date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, phpmyadmin

I have a Excel file (.xlsx) and I am trying to import it using phpMyAdmin.
(not using .csv)

In the Excel file I have in the first row the headers of the fields from my table and the rest of the rows is the data I want to import like below..

[image]

As you can see Colum B contains the date and time. (yyyy-mm-dd  hh:mm:ss)

In phpMyAdmin I have the table set up as the following:

[image]

When I now go to the 'Import' section to import the Excel file I selected the following:

[image]

I then clicked on 'Go' to import the file.

When I do that the date & time field converted to a number like the following:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make it so that the date & time is the same as per the Excel file ?

In Excel I did format that cell to be custom yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss

[image]

Any ideas on why this is not importing correctly ?
(I did try saving the file as .xls but got the same result.)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The spreadsheet is preserving the data in its original format when saved and the cell format is loaded separately after that. Obviously phpmyadmin doesn't pick up this trap and loads the formatted data.

Saving your sheet as a CSV should work. You can open the CSV in notepad to confirm that the CSV version contains the correct date format.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. Since Excel is writing to an .xls file, it is using the Excel standard for storing a date which is not yyy-mm-dd -- yes, that's how it's *displaying* in Excel but that's not how it's stored. Whether or not phpMyAdmin should deal better with this, the quick and optimal solution is to use CSV instead. I've created an item in the phpMyAdmin issue tracker to discuss this: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11722

Comment: This is the best answer -- in fact, Excel support was removed from phpMyAdmin some time ago so CSV is really the best choice in this case regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you save file as
**OpenDocument Spreadsheet(.ods)** from **Excel** 
and importing into **phpMyAdmin** with **OpenDocument Spreadsheet** format.